# Does anyone have an example how to start the web browser with Tokio delphi for an android application?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I need to start google.map from an Android Delphi application to send location and navigation information.

I used `TWebBrowser` but the navigation does not work.

```
URLString := 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:' + FloatToStr( ActiveLattitude ) +',' + FloatToStr( ActiveLongiture ) + '&destination=' + lblAdresse.Text + '&navigate=yes';
wbRouteCNew.Navigate(URLString);
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Have you confirmed your URL is correct?

Comment: If I go on the road with the tablet, it does not start navigation. It shows the route but does not locate the navigation. I use a SIM card in the tablet with an internet connection.

Comment: Again, what does the actual content of your `URLString` look like? You are not url-encoding the individual query values at all, particularly the `destination`. So you may be passing a malformed url to Google.

Comment: In fact, your url does not match [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) at all. You are using completely different parameters than what is documented

Comment: My URLString: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&dir_action=navigate&destination=3054 rue BUGLE CALL SAINT-LAZARE QC, J7T 2B1&travelmode=driving&key=[YOUR API KEY]

Comment: No, it's ok, if you run directly in the explorer it works on tablet or windows but not in delphi for an android application.

Comment: Most browsers will URL encode spaces entered in the URL bar. The same won't be done for strings passed in by code.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers will URL encode spaces etc that are entered in the URL bar for you. The same will not be done for URLs passed in using code to browser components. The following is an invalid URL:

```
http://example.com/?street=1 Rue Street
```

but when entered into the chrome address bar it will fix it up:

```
http://example.com/?street=1%20Rue%20Street
```

Post the exact string you are trying to pass using the code - we can't reproduce anything with no values given to the variables. As some suggested you are likely not URL encoding some parameters that need it but none of us can tell for sure.